# selenium validate text box area color

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium-web driver with node.js.

I have test scenario like validate "enter the valid order number and empty zipcode". In this test case when I enter the data and click on submit button, the text area is highlighted with red color.

My question is how to validate the text area color?
When inspecting the page, `css` color also not there:

[image: this is the image of validation]

How can I validate the text area color?

[which attribute shall I select in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izeEq.png)

Comment: You can get the css property using the `getCssValue` method, but you need to know the attribute that is setting the css color.

Comment: I have added the inspect element of that page. Can you please tell me which attribute shall I select. @demouser123

Comment: `I enter the data and click on submit button, the text area is highlighted with red color.` - in your screenshot, the area is highlighted even without any input. Can you give DOM and CSS when you enter the data and click.

Comment: Thanks for replying @demouser123
now it is working fine. I have used like this,
.then((element) => element.getCssValue("border-color")

Comment: Thanks for replying. can you please let me know whether i am using right commands are not @demouser123

Comment: You're correct!

Comment: Thanks for looking in this issue @demouser123